# Give anonymous access to one page while site has Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication, anonymous-users

I have already tried for Location tag and allow `users = *`  ... but even then it is prompting for a password for the page.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Hope you don't mind, but I removed the long footer you've had there - this isn't the proper place for a signature and other comments. You can use your [user page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/382003) for such messages `:)`.

Comment: Try this answer...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492977/anonymous-access-and-ntlm-authentication-in-iis